# Calculate number of common neighbors in igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

Can anyone help me to find the number of common neighbors of two vertices using igraph R.

I tried to get this with following command but it returned with `list()`.

```
intersect(neighborhood(graph=TD1,order=1,nodes=714),neighborhood(graph=TD1,order=1,nodes=4211))

>>>> list()
```

Thanks

Anna

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neighborhood()` returns a list of integer vectors, one for each source node you passed in. Since you only have a single source node, you have to extract the first element of the list that `neighborhood()` returns before passing them to `intersect()`:

```
intersect(
    neighborhood(graph=TD1, order=1, nodes=714)[[1]],
    neighborhood(graph=TD1, order=1, nodes=4211)[[1]]
)
```